# Copy LINQ results to data set/table

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, linq-to-entities

I’m working on a form that has a few data grid views that are populated from LINQ queries, no problem there it works as it should however that sorting does not work. After doing some reading its because LINQ results do not support sorting.

As I have the LINQ results already is there a way of copying the results into a dataset or datatable then binding the data grid view to that so sorting will work?

Thanks

EDIT:
Thanks to everyone for the answers, sadly I'm off on holiday for 2 weeks so cant try out and upvote the correct one. However when I return it will be on the top of my list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I used bits from each option and a little tweak to get it to work with nullable fields.

First thing is getting the CopyToDataTable function into VB, this is done here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx

When I tried this it would fail if the column was nullable so I searched and found a mod to that code that would work. Here it is in full

```
Public Function ExtendTable(ByVal table As DataTable, ByVal type As Type) As DataTable
     For Each f As FieldInfo In type.GetFields()
       If (Not _ordinalMap.ContainsKey(f.Name)) Then
         Dim dc As DataColumn
         dc = If(table.Columns.Contains(f.Name), table.Columns(f.Name), table.Columns.Add(f.Name, f.FieldType))
         _ordinalMap.Add(f.Name, dc.Ordinal)
       End If
     Next f
     For Each p As PropertyInfo In type.GetProperties()
       If Not _ordinalMap.ContainsKey(p.Name) Then
         Dim colType As Type = p.PropertyType
         If (colType.IsGenericType) AndAlso (colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() Is GetType(Nullable(Of ))) Then
           colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()(0)
         End If
         Dim dc As DataColumn = IIf(table.Columns.Contains(p.Name), table.Columns(p.Name), table.Columns.Add(p.Name, colType))
         _ordinalMap.Add(p.Name, dc.Ordinal)
       End If
     Next
     Return table
    End Function
```

Upvotes all round as they all would have worked I just took this option as it is neater

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx) extension method for this.

The standard implementation of this method only works over `IEnumerable<T>` where T is of type `DataRow` but there is an example on MSDN of making your own [extension method which works on anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx).

---

I've actually not used `CopyToDataTable`, in the past I've created a similar end result by creating a BindingList which supports sorting and then creating an instance of it with the query as the IList in the constructor, but the CopyToDataTable approach looks a lot cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1):

In C# I do it thus:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("a", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("b", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("c", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("d", Type.GetType("System.String"));

        foreach (var row in [linqQueryName] )
        {
            DataRow destRow = dt.NewRow();
            destRow["a"] = row.linqCol1;
            destRow["b"] = row.linqCol2;
            destRow["c"] = row.linqCol3;
            destRow["d"] = row.linqCol4;
            dt.Rows.Add(destRow);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

See the code:

Here testData is the data from LINQ query on a list of Class having ID and Name as properties

```
  Dim dataTable As New DataTable()
        dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
        For Each item As var In testData
        Dim dataRow As DataRow = dataTable.NewRow()
        dataRow("ID") = item.ID
        dataRow("Name") = item.Name
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow)
        Next
```